# I can't find the error, so who can tell me, thanks

Tags: node.js

```
/Users/mac/page/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;      
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right there...   Where it says `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

That's the error.

Comment: User.find(req.body.username,function(err,user) //here,it's error,but I don't known
  {
    if(!user){
      return err;
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    if(user.password!=password){
      return err;
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    req.session.user=user;
    req.flash('success','登陆成功');

    res.redirect('/');
  });